Issue with postgre database creation in Kali Linux
I just installed postgresql 16 on my Kali Linux. It's working perfectly but when I try to create a database (using the correct command line), it gives me this feedback :
postgres=# create database Danny;
ERROR:  template database "template1" has a collation version mismatch
DETAIL:  The template database was created using collation version 2.37, but the operating system provides version 2.38.
HINT:  Rebuild all objects in the template database that use the default collation and run ALTER DATABASE template1 REFRESH COLLATION VERSION, or build PostgreSQL with the right library version.

I want to know how to solve this error and continue with database creation in postgre.
How can I rectify this problem?

Did you try anything so far? The error itself gives you suggestions and googling the error returns very many hits. Did none of those help? Please show us what you have tried so we don't waste your time with solutions you have already attempted. Also, are you sure you want to do this on Kali?

and what is the correct command line? According to whom? For which usage?

@MarcusMüller presumably the create database Danny;, which does seem like a correct command.

agreed, but there's a template database from another version, so I'm guessing there's more than that. I'd assume "the correct command line" is the invocation of the DB client, but I'm not sure! I wish Daniel would clarify that, so that's where my comment comes from!

@MarcusMüller No. The template database is created automatically with the cluster. It's very rare to request a database from a different template.

@PhilipCouling yes, that was my understanding. So, either this is an downgrade from an existing database installation (on Kali?!) or something strange is going on, and us guessing all the steps that lead to where Daniel is will not work.

@MarcusMüller I strongly suspect "all the steps" are litteraly install via apt-get install and later create a database as shown. But there is likely an apt-get upgrade somewhere in between that the OP may not remember. The template DB is on an older version that the core system library now installed.

I suspect this has something to do with Kali's choice of using a Rolling release strategy. Version mismatches are much more likely this way that with other distributions like Ubuntu or Debian.  Kali is, of course designed for pen-testing and not a general use distribution.
You've most likely triggered with a system upgrade:
apt-get upgrade

The error is telling you that the template database (which was created duing the inintial apt-get install postgresql does not now match the installed core library responsible for collation.
It's effectivly this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/324649/7472. For sorting ("Collating") postgresql uses the operating system's own library. This means that if the OS sort order changes, postgressql might accidently corrupt an index. (immagine putting someone's name in the wrong place in a phone book... you'd never find it!)
So the error you are seeing is that the template database template1, which was created when you installed postgresql, expects version 2.37 but the installed core system library is now 2.38.
The answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/330184/7472 should help you.  I believe, you need to use the interactive commandline tool psql to issue the following instructions to postgresql:
REINDEX DATABASE template0;

ALTER DATABASE template0 REFRESH COLLATION VERSION;

I have no way to test this for myself, so I can't garentee the above will work.

I think there’s more to it than the rolling release strategy: all PostgreSQL 16 packages are built from a single source package, and that’s the basic unit for version upgrades and publication.

@StephenKitt correct me if I’m wrong but Postgres documentation cites that collation comes from the wider OS not posgresql code base. I take that to mean sort uses the same collation as Postgres. Notwithstanding, I refer to Kali’s rolling release mostly because users get little warning before major version bumps where a Debian user would need to deliberately upgrade to a later OS release.

@StephenKitt When using the GNU C library for collations, the C library's version is used as a proxy for the collation version. Many Linux distributions change collation definitions only when upgrading the C library, but this approach is imperfect as maintainers are free to back-port newer collation definitions to older C library releases.

Ah, I see, thanks! I was thinking of version mismatches between the PostgreSQL server and client (or libraries). You’re right, only a rolling release would get a major libc version upgrade.
